# Is "sound approach" an accepted phrase?

Tags: meaning, adjectives, word-usage, orthography, collocation

English is not my first language, and in my language (Bosnian) we write just as we speak ; so from time to time, I encounter phrases which I know I have heard before, but am not sure if I am writing them correctly.

Do you say *sound approach* to describe an approach to a problem which is logical, makes sense, and is practical?

The reason I ask is that I could not find it in a reliable online reference, and I have a feeling that I am spelling it wrong.

Comment: Do you have some impression that in English, one writes other than how one speaks?

Comment: I think "sound approach" works well in your sentence. Please see http://english.stackexchange.com/a/50614/3306 for "sound engineering."

Comment: @tchrist  I believe OP means that English orthography is not consistently either phonetic or phonemic, so he suspects that his failure to find his phrase in a dictionary is attributable to his now knowing the correct spelling.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Dolphin, where the comments are frequently more educational than the answers. You may not find *sound approach* in dictionaries, but you will find the adjective *sound* - [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sound), for instance, sense 3.

Comment: Thanks to all, I have to say you are very helpful and nice group.

Comment: Least we could do for the questioner who rolled our count over to 20,000. By the way, as you may see from the citations in tchrist's answer, English spelling was even harder four or five hundred years ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Used as adjective, *sound* can  per the OED mean:

> In full accordance with fact, reason, or good sense; founded on true or well-established grounds; free from error, fallacy, or logical defect; good, strong, valid.

And it is this sense that is operative here.  They give four citations that appear especially relevant, albeit not especially recent:

> - C. 1440 Capgrave *Life St. Kath.* ᴠ. 1183 ― Youre counseyll in this is neyther saue ne sounde.
> - 1576 Gascoigne *Steele Gl.* (Arb.) 52 ― And sound advice might ease hir wearie thoughtes.
> - 1596 *Edw. III*, ɪ. i. 101 ― The soundest counsell I can giue his grace, Is to surrender ere he be constraynd.
> - 1697 Dryden *Æneid* xɪɪ. 42 ― Sound Advice, proceeding from a heart Sincerely yours.

In summary, I should say that your approach is therefore sound.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, *a sound approach* is accepted and idiomatic English. Here's what Merriam-Webster says about *[sound](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sound)*:

> 3
>   a : free from error, fallacy, or misapprehension [sound reasoning]
>   b : exhibiting or based on thorough knowledge and experience [sound scholarship]
>   c : legally valid [a sound title]
>   d : logically valid and having true premises
>   e : agreeing with accepted views : orthodox

You should try the dictionary before asking. Then ask a search engine to answer your question. Google, for example, show about 71,900,000 hits for *[a sound approach](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&newwindow=1&safe=off&tbo=d&q=a%20sound%20approach&oq=%20a%20sound%20approach&gs_l=serp.1.0.0j0i30l6j0i8.1512555.1512555.0.1517719.1.1.0.0.0.0.159.159.0j1.1.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.SmkHqwJ-QaQ)*. They usually help and preclude the need to ask for help from others. We have this famous old saying in English: **[God helps those who help themselves](http://www.gotquestions.org/God-help-themselves.htm)**. It's a platitude, but one worth testing every day.

Comment: When you google - `a sound approach` this page is first result so guess google needed some help.